# Displaying authors in color bibtex

Tags: bibtex, color, natbib

If I call a reference by `\citet{xxx}`, it appears in my document  as `Author [number]`, where the number appears in the color I  defined in `\hypersetup{citecolor=red}` while `Author` and `[]` appear in black color.
The `natbib` options I am using are:

```
\usepackage[square,colon,sort&compress,numbers]{natbib}
```

Would it be possible to make the entire reference (`Author[number]`) appears in red color? or at least the Author and the number?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[square,colon,sort&compress,numbers,nonamebreak]{natbib}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,citecolor=red,linkcolor=red}

\begin{document}

blablabla \citet{Ref1} blabla.....

\newpage
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{BibliographyFile}

\end{document}

@article{Ref1, 
author    = "Author1, A1. and Author2, A2.",
title     = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
journal   = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
volume    = "YY",
number    = "ZZ",
year      = "XXXX",
url={web},
pages     = "x-y",
}
```

---

a MWE is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[square,colon,sort&compress,numbers,nonamebreak]{natbib}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,citecolor=red,linkcolor=red}

\begin{document}

blablabla \citet{Ref1} blabla.....

\newpage
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{BibliographyFile}

\end{document}

@article{Ref1, 
author    = "Author1, A1. and Author2, A2.",
title     = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
journal   = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
volume    = "YY",
number    = "ZZ",
year      = "XXXX",
url={web},
pages     = "x-y",
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your question and welcome to the [TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Could you please add a fully compilable (minimum working) example ([MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), best with some bib file as well? It would help the solvers a lot.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.